# Xcode: not show warning in issue navigator

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I have an Xcode project with plenty of warning (I know this is bad).

However I would like to use the Issue Navigator to locate errors? The problem is that all the warning are literally polluting the Navigator so it is unusable.

Is there any way to do that?

Please do not answer me that I should remove this warning. I would like to do that but can not  for the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the recently the solution.
there is a little button at the bottom of the navigator screen. It does exactly what I need.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could edit your Xcode project settings and add the custom compiler flag `-w` to suppress all warnings.

You are in a bad place though...

Comment: @KevinMOLCARD It's only temporary until you decide to start fixing the warnings.  It can be easily undone.